# How to configure scratch application in my local system (windows 7) ??

Tags: php, apache, cakephp, memcached, mit-scratch

I am very new to the technologies which are being used in the development of Scratch(MIT) application. Since I need to fork/create a local repository for Scratch(MIT), I m finding it difficult to achieve. Anyone can help to find a good tutorial for the same. I've been googling all around but all in vein.

Below is the link of their repo on SVN

http://svn.assembla.com/svn/scratchr

Comment: take a look at http://svn.assembla.com/svn/scratchr/INSTALL.txt

Answer (score 1):

Look for SVN tutorials and checkout the code by giving this URL repository. Then look at cakePHP tutorials. And then read Install.txt of this repository.

Comment: :- I did the same. But while running the project i am getting the following errors:

( ! ) Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in E:\wamp\www\scratchr\cake\basics.php on line 1101

( ! ) Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in E:\wamp\www\scratchr\cake\libs\inflector.php on line 67

( ! ) Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in E:\wamp\www\scratchr\cake\libs\configure.php on line 124

Comment: your wamp is using some advance version of php. See the project information, what version of php it needs, then download wamp that supports that PHP version